# a pratical example for the computation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I'm working with a problem with conditional expectation

$\Omega=[0,1)$. $P(A)$ is Lebesgue measure of $A\in\mathcal{B}[0,1)$

$f:[0,1)\to\mathcal{R}$ is bounded. $X(w):=f(w),w\in\Omega$

$\mathcal{G}_N=\sigma\{[\frac{j}{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n})|n\leq N,0\leq j \leq 2^n-1\}$

How can I compute $E(X|\mathcal{G}_N),N\geq1$ ? I'm quite confused about the concept of conditional expectation.

I think I need help with an example for $N=1$ and  $N=2$ Then I think I can do a induction to solve this.

And I also need some help with $\lim_{N\to \infty} E(X|\mathcal{G}_N)$

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: As a start, do you know what the $\mathcal G_N$-measurable functions look like?

Comment: Nope, actually I did not learn much about measure theory and just directly study this course. From the text book my current idea is to use the smallest interval of $\mathcal{G}_N$ , which is $w_{N,k}=[\frac{k}{2^N},\frac{k+1}{2^N})$ to express (or construct?) other non-empty $A\in\mathcal{G}_N$ and written $E(X|\mathcal{G}_N)$ as some kind of $\sum_i \frac{1}{2^N} f(w_{N,k})$. But this is some kind of guess and I'm not quite sure about this.

Comment: I'm writting $E(X\mathcal{I}_A)$